# sscanf & newlines

Tags: c, newline, eof, scanf

I need to parse a response from a server like this:

risposta:

```
200\n
Len 1040\n
Expire 30\n
\n
1111111111111111111111111\n
1111111111111111111111111\n
1111111111111111111111111\n
```

I'm trying with sscanf:

```
sscanf(risposta, "%d\nLen %d\nExpire %d\n\n%s[^\0]", &risp->type, &risp->len, &risp->expire, risp->risorsa);
```

but it puts only 1111111111111111111111111 in risp->risorsa.
How to resolve?

P.s. struct risp:

```
typedef struct Server_risp {
   int type;
   int expire;
   int len;
   int sup;
   int inf;
   char risorsa[5000];
 }Server_risp;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A scanset specification is not `%s[whatever]`, it's just `%[whatever]`, so your format string should be more like: `"%d\nLen %d\nExpire %d\n\n%[^\0]"`.

As a side note, `scanf` and friend consider any white space in a format string is equivalent to any other whitespace -- any whitespace in the format matches an arbitrary sequence of whitespace characters in the input (and a new-line is considered whitespace). Your current format string does a nice job of documenting the format you expect, but from a viewpoint of what it really matches, you can change it to something like: `"%d Len %d Expire %d %[^\0]"` without affecting what it'll do. In particular, your two consecutive new-lines aren't really accomplishing much.

Edit: Thinking about it, the `[\0]` causes just a bit of a problem: the "\0" terminates the string, so you end up with an invalid scan-set specification. Since you just want the rest of the input to go into `risorsa`, it's probably easiest to use `%c`: `"%d Len %d Expire %d %4999c"`.

And yes, this time I actually tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *riposta = "200\n"
    "Len 1040\nExpire 30\n"
    "\n1111111111111111111111111\n"
    "1111111111111111111111111\n"
    "1111111111111111111111111\n";

typedef struct Server_risp {
    int type;
    int expire;
    int len;
    int sup;
    int inf;
    char risorsa[5000];
}Server_risp;

int main() {
    Server_risp risp;
   sscanf(riposta, "%d Len %d Expire %d %4999c", &risp.type, &risp.len, &risp.expire, risp.risorsa);

   printf("%s\n", risp.risorsa);
}
```

result:

```
1111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111
```

Edit 2: I'm not sure exactly what problem you're running into here. I modified it a bit to show reading both leading and embedded white-space:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *riposta = "200\n"
"Len 1040\nExpire 30\n"
"|        |"
"\n1111111111111111111111111\n"
"1111111111111111111111111\n"
"1111111111111111111111111\n";

typedef struct Server_risp {
    int type;
    int expire;
    int len;
    int sup;
    int inf;
    char risorsa[5000];
}Server_risp;

int main() {
    Server_risp risp;
    sscanf(riposta, "%d Len %d Expire %d%4999c", &risp.type, &risp.len, &risp.expire, risp.risorsa);

    printf("%s\n", risp.risorsa);
}
```

...and got pretty much the expected result:

```
|        |
1111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: I've tried with %[^\0], but it doesn't put anything in risp->risorsa, neither the first line.

Comment: Hint: Tried with: %[^\a] it works..but I need to parse everything until EOF.

Is there something wrong with \0? In fact gcc says:
parser.c:163: warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format
parser.c:163: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format

Comment: New Problem related this:
%4999c solution trunks responde with blankspace at initials like:

char *riposta = "200\n"
    "Len 1040\nExpire 30\n"
    "__________1111111111111111111111111\n"
    "1111111111111111111111111\n"
    "1111111111111111111111111\n";

risp->risorsa needs to be
__________1111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111

Very important: I've used _ to simulate " "

Comment: If you need to keep the leading blanks, delete the blank immediately before the `%c`, so it's like "%d Len %d Expire %d%4999c".

Comment: Ok Jerry it works now :D
I've added something like:
for (i=0; i<strlen(risp_aux->risorsa); i++){
  p_aux = &risp_aux->risorsa[2+i];
  risp_aux->risorsa[i]=*(p_aux);
  }
to remove \n\n at beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out a way around the problem in:

```
sscanf(risposta, "%d\nLen %d\nExpire %d\n\n%s[^\0]", &risp->type, &risp->len, &risp->expire, risp->risorsa);
```

the problem in the code being that '\0' terminates the string prior to the closing bracket ']'. You could use '\1'. Then, the string is not prematurely terminated, and sscanf will continue scanning until it runs out of string.

The corrected code would be:

```
sscanf(risposta, "%d\nLen %d\nExpire %d\n\n%s[^\1]", &risp->type, &risp->len, &risp->expire, risp->risorsa);
```

Maybe that is what you wanted to do in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

There are some problems about following code:

```
sscanf(risposta, "%d\nLen %d\nExpire %d\n\n%s[^\0]", &risp->type, &risp->len, &risp->expire, risp->risorsa);
```

It should be:

```
char tmp_str[100]; 

sscanf(risposta, "%d %s %d %s %d %s[^\0]", &risp->type, tmp_str, &risp->len, tmp_str, &risp->expire, risp->risorsa);
```

You should handle the string "Len" and "Expire", and sscanf can not handle it.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but the advice you're giving is wrong, *and* you haven't addressed the real problem.

Comment: I don't need to handle "Len" or "Expire", just their integer.
However, %s[^\0] puts only first line:
    printf("%s%d\n%d\n%d\n%s\n%s",ORANGE,risp->type,risp->len,risp->expire,risp->risorsa,WHITE);

200
1040
30
1111111111111111111111111